# MongoDB database design - contest application

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database

I'm building a contest application. Which have 4 collections so far:

1. `contest`
2. `questions`
3. `matches`
4. `users`

I want to store every `user` score for every `match` he's assigned into. But I really can't find a proper way to achieve this.

All what I've came up with, Is to replace `matches` in `users` with an array in which each element contains a reference to `matches` collection and `score` field. But I think this is not very efficient.

---

**EDIT**

I was thinking about another solution. A separate collection called `scores` that contains three fields `user`, `match` and `score`.

---

Here's my schema structure:

**Contests**:
[image]

**Questions**:
[image]

**Matches**:
[image]

**Users**:
[image]

**Note** Any recommended adjustments on the current design is welcomed too.

Comment: Put the `answers` and `matches` in `questions` is OK, because there is not push change (update) required.

But about Users this link may help you (rad my answer to the question) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430320/mongodb-database-design-contest-application

Comment: @Disposer beware that the limit of each doccument can not be more than 16mb, so if it surpass that, It would be a problem. But in terms of performance that would be the best option. Also he does not says that he does not need to update them.

Comment: All I'm saying is that if you update your inside arrays (push new items or removing from them) don't use sub-documents, design separated collection for them and a new collection  for relation between them (and put a proper compound-index relation collection). Why? pushing and removing items cause to (not always) move a document and moving a document is not good for mongo. in separated collection design you will get maximum performance but kinda you will lose atomicity (trade-off). In this way you will never reach 16-MB max size but the BEST performance.

Answer (score 0):

Since mongodb is not designed to support collections relationships you migth end up with some duplicated work, I would suggest you to find a way of storing as much data as you can in a single document.

Your scores would go in each match document, probably the users array would have this structure {'users':[{user_id:'xxx',score:xxx}{user_id:'xxx',score:xxx}]}

The other solution, would be what you say, to have in each user doccument, a matches array with a structure like this: {'matches':[{match_id:'xxx',score:xxx}{match_id:'xxx',score:xxx}]}

You can have both also, this migth be more efficient depending the kind of queries you will need to do. You can also have a field in the subdocuments that stores the user/match name/title

Note: As you can see, you have two solutions, or you optimize for doccument size(so you can store more) or you optimize for performance (so you can read faster/with less resources)

Hope this be of any help.